# Is PMNS neutrino mixing allowed in the standard model?

Tags: standard-model, neutrinos, elementary-particles

Some people say that the standard model does not allow for non-zero neutrino masses: it prevents renormalization, they say.

Other people say that massive neutrinos with PMNS mixing are allowed in the standard model.

Who is right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix "In the simplest case, the Standard Model posits three generations of neutrinos with Dirac mass that oscillate between three neutrino mass eigenvalues". ..so it seems that neutrino with mixing is considered to be part of the SM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter bunch is right, but you have to shake both groups and demand to know what *they* mean by the SM, a  terminology famously "invented expressly to be systematically abused"!

If you take the SM to mean the standard chiral gauge theory SSBroken by a Higgs field, there is nothing preventing Dirac neutrino masses; historically, Weinberg in 1967 did not put them in, as they were not apparent experimentally, and you don't spatchcock a simple model including speculative states and couplings for no reason. Since the originalist conceit may sow confusion, early on after the advent of the Weinberg-Salam model, well-meaning adults (Pais and Treiman) introduced the adaptable and inclusive term SM to precisely *avoid arid doctrinaire discussions* on proprietary models. It is adapted to cover the (evolving!) contemporary understanding of the landscape, consistent with the basic telltale chiral gauge group structure...

Consequently, the theory has conceptual "slots" for them, and is quite comfortable with them. The PMNS mixing, then, including extensions for Majorana masses,  can be soundly a piece of the SM.

Admittedly, neutrino masses of meVs, so, 14 orders of magnitude away from  that of the top quark, although speculated to arise from similar couplings, are giving pause to students of renormalization in the SM; these have major problems with the stability of huge/minuscule ratio numbers under renormalization. But their methodological and conceptual problems ("naturalness") are theirs alone, and their starting points are not a dispositive part of the SM, a basically effective theory describing TeV-and-below physics.

Comment: Thank you. My friend's manuscript got refused by a (good!) journal because the manuscript stated that neutrino masses and PMNS mixing are allowed in the standard model. The editors wrote that neutrino masses were IMPOSSIBLE in the standard model, and any paper claiming so must be rejected.

Comment: The original SM did not contain neutrino masses, but the extension to include them is trivial, so the question is open.  I believe that Glashow once stated that the  SM does not contain neutrino masses, and that as it was his model he had the right to say what was in it, but I'm afraid I can't find a reference for the quote.

Comment: Sorry to hear anyone will fuss about names so stridently; your friend could finesse the issue by circumlocutions like "neutrino masses allowed/accommodated  by the chiral structure of the SM", etc... @RogerBarlow Yes, the originalist conceit may sow confusion, but SM was a term introduced by Pais and Treiman to precisely avoid what Glashow, or Weinberg or Salam, etc... had in their models, or not. It is adapted to cover contemporary understanding of the landscape, consistent with the basic chiral gauge group structure...